# Удаление файлов с помощью php

Tags: php

Есть папка `images`, в ней 100000 файлов. 10000 нужно удалить. Имена файлов известны.

Чтобы удалить один файл:

```
<?php if (unlink('images/4e4cc0c3fa943d620e946f281c719dc9.jpg')) { echo "Файл удален"; } else { echo "Ошибка при удалении файла"; } ?>
```

Чтобы удалить несколько, думала будет так:

```
<?php $files = file('./files.txt');
foreach ($files as $file) if (is_file($path = './images/' . $file)) unlink($path); ?>
```

Но удаляется только последний указанный файл из `files.txt`.

Что нужно подправить, чтобы все удалились?

Comment: Фрагментация же

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?
if ($f = fopen('./files.txt', 'rb')) {
  $del = 0;
  while (!feof($f)) {
    $fname = trim(fgets($f));
    if (!$fname) continue;
    if (is_file($path = './images/' . trim($fname)) and unlink($path))
      $del++;
  } 
  fclose($f);
  echo 'deleted: '.$del;
} else echo 'error';
?>
```

Попробуйте так. Вообще косяк только в отсутствии `trim()`, так как функция `file()` разбивает текст по `\n`, соответственно пробелы-табуляции и виндовское `\r` остается в предполагаемом имени файла. Но пути `/images/123.jpg\r` естественно нет) Ну и оптимизация - нехорошо грузить массив из 10000 строк в память при наличии другого способа.

Comment: Спасибо, так все отлично работает.

>при наличии другого способа
Это Вы о чем? Об удалении вручную?

Answer (score 1):

Как понимаю, имена всех файлов, которые надо удалить, лежат здесь: `'./files.txt'`
Так вот, функция [file()](http://www.php.su/functions/?file) читает файл не построчно, а целостно, то есть одним фрагментом. Данная функция практически идентична [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.su/functions/?file-get-contents).
Чтобы удалить все файлы, надо сначала прочитать содержимое `'./files.txt'`, а затем разбить его построчно на фрагменты (1 фрагмент = 1 имени файла). Сделать это можно с помощью регулярок, но еще легче так:

```
<?php 
$files_content = file('./files.txt');
$files = explode('\r',$files_content);
...
?>
```

**UPD:**

Но даже после этих маниуляций препроцессор PHP выдаст вам сообщение об ошибке! Это произойдет потому, что 10000 файлов не смогут удалиться в течение установленного лимита( по умолчанию = 30 сек.). Тут вам уже придется подумать и понять, что можно разбить удаление файлов на 3-5 шагов (1 шаг = 1 обновление страницы) и в каждом шаге удалять 10000/n файлов(n - кол-во шагов).

**P.S** Вообще в PHP не стоит работать с такими большими массивами данных. PHP создан для быстрого доступа и анализа поступаемых данных, а не для выполнения рутины, поэтому лучше позаботьтесь о своевременном удалении файлов, когда их ещё мало...

Comment: Asen, досталось по наследству.
Сейчас я вручную удаляю файлы, в день 5-7. Не много. Просто боюсь такое кол-во буду год удалять, хотелось сразу удалить.
Но не суть..

К сожалению, указанный Вами код не помогает, файлы вообще не удаляются.

Comment: В моем коде файлы и не должны удаляться. Просто код надо вставить в нужное место, которое вы должны увидеть сами.

Comment: Я это понимаю. Моих познаний хватило на то, чтобы удалялся последний файл (снова). 
В любом случае спасибо, буду изучать вопрос до удаления файлов :)

Comment: Да, изучайте. И не только вопрос, изучайте PHP в целом.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так можно попробовать. Рекурсивно удалять.

```
<?
  function full_del_dir ($directory)
  {
  $dir = opendir($directory);
  while(($file = readdir($dir)))
  {
    if ( is_file ($directory."/".$file))
    {
      unlink ($directory."/".$file);
    }
    else if ( is_dir ($directory."/".$file) &&
             ($file != ".") && ($file != ".."))
    {
      full_del_dir ($directory."/".$file);  
    }
  }
  closedir ($dir);
  rmdir ($directory);
  echo("Каталог успешно удален");
  }
  full_del_dir ("path_to_directory")
?>
```

Comment: При чем здесь каталог?

Answer (score 0):

возьми всё в массив 
если всё храниться в массиве $c, то

```
 foreach($c as $key => $val) {
        $file_name = "photoalbum/" . $PhotoAlbumName . "/" . basename($c[$key]);
        if(file_exists($file_name)) {
            unlink($file_name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$files = file('./files.txt');

foreach($files as $file) 
foreach ($files as $file) 
if (is_file($path = './images/' . @trim("$file"))) unlink($path); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант.

```
$folder = 'images';
foreach (glob("$folder/*.*") as $file) {
  unlink($file);
}
```